# Split PyCharm edit window on a Mac?

Tags: editing, pycharm, split-window

Does anyone know how to split the PyCharm edit window on a Mac.  The website instructions appear to be for Windows.  In any case, they don't apply on my machine because I am not seeing any tabs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I do:

1. install vim plugin
2. Ctrl-w s or Ctrl-w v

Not sure how it's done without the vim plugin though.